# Is it possible to remove or hide suggestions of last entries from @Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

When I want to add new entry to @Html.EditorFor I can see suggestions of my last entries. Look at the picture below.

[image]

Is there any way to remove or hide the suggestins?

My code:

```
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.NR_PRZESYLKI_EX)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.NR_PRZESYLKI_EX)
        </td>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: I think this is the browser's autocomplete functionality. You can try to turn it off via this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3015847/6996150 . But in Chrome it's notoriously difficult to stop the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.NR_PRZESYLKI_EX, new { autocomplete="off" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.NR_PRZESYLKI_EX)
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.
@sheavens your code doesn't work for me :(
@johey your suggestion solve the problem...